# Unauthorized (401) when I try to access JIRA REST API with PHP

Tags: php, curl, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to use JIRA REST API with PHP. When I copy the url below and paste it straight into the browser it works fine. The resulting issue is returned as json.

But with the code below it doesn't work. I get Unauthorized (401) as a return message. Yes, I have checked and double checked that the credentials are valid. This is my code:

```
$username = 'username';
$password = 'psw';
$url = "https://mycompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/XXX-123";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
echo $result;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Solution: Use username and not email when providing credentials.

It turns out, even if you login with your email in JIRA, it's not the email you use here, but the username, which can be found in Jira->Settings->Profile

Comment: Yes, in my case the username was just the part before the @ (not the whole email address), and then it logged me right in.

Comment: Shot this is great, Had me fooled for a sec or two

Comment: Can't believe this is still not mentioned in the documentation at Atlassian. Or at least I couldn't find it...

Comment: Thanks, yes its not the email, its the username on JIRA profile.

Comment: I lost 2 hours on this... damn JIRA

Comment: seriously atlasian, get ur <censored> together

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove `https://` part from url.

Try to add

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
```